# Triangular polkadot numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

From the infinite triangular array of positive integers, suppose we select every 2nd numbers on every 2nd row as shown below:

$$
\underline{1} \\
\;2\; \quad \;3\; \\
\;\underline{4}\; \quad \;5\; \quad \;\underline{6}\; \\
\;7\; \quad \;8\; \quad \;9\; \quad 10 \\
\underline{11} \quad 12 \quad \underline{13} \quad 14 \quad \underline{15} \\
16 \quad 17 \quad 18 \quad 19 \quad 20 \quad 21 \\
\underline{22} \quad 23 \quad \underline{24} \quad 25 \quad \underline{26} \quad 27 \quad \underline{28} \\
\cdots
$$

The resulting sequence ([A185868](http://oeis.org/A185868)) is as follows:

```
1, 4, 6, 11, 13, 15, 22, 24, 26, 28, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66,
79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 106, 108, 110, 112, 114, 116, 118, 120, 137, ...
```

The task is to output this sequence.

[sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) I/O rules apply. You can choose to implement one of the following:

- Given the index \$n\$ (0- or 1-based), output the \$n\$th term of the sequence.
- Given a positive integer \$n\$, output the first \$n\$ terms of the sequence.
- Take no input and output the entire sequence by

  - printing infinitely or
  - returning a lazy list or a generator.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: The phrasing of the first sentence makes it seem like you are given the triangular array as an input.

Comment: @97.100.97.109 Does it look better now?

Comment: I think so, though you could be even more clear by phrasing it as something besides a command, e.g. "Imagine taking every second number..." or "Suppose we took every second number..."

Answer (score 13):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 35 bytes (@att)

```python
lambda n:int((2*n)**.5-.5)**2+2*n-1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3lXMSc5NSEhXyrDLzSjQ0jLTyNLW09Ex19UyBtJE2kK9rCFWqkJZfpJCnkJmnUJSYl56qYahjZKBpVVAE0pimkaepCVG3YAGEBgA)

#### [Python](https://www.python.org), 39 bytes

```python
lambda n:(int((8*n)**.5-1)//2)**2+2*n-1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY31XMSc5NSEhXyrDQy80o0NCy08jS1tPRMdQ019fWNgEwjbSOtPF1DqHKFtPwihTyFzDyFosS89FQNQx0jA02rgiKQ3jSNPE1NiLoFCyA0AA)

Given the 1-based index computes a single value.

Comment: [-4 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3lXMSc5NSEhXyrDLzSjQ0jLTyNLW09Ex19UyBtJE2kK9rCFWqkJZfpJCnkJmnUJSYl56qYahjZKBpVVAE0pimkaepCVG3YAGEBgA)

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

Outputs the sequence indefinitely.

```python
n=x=1
while 1:exec'2;print x;x+='*n+'n-~n';n+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8@2wtaQqzwjMydVwdAqtSI1Wd3IuqAoM69EocK6QttWXStPWz1Pty5P3TpP29bw/38A)

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 34 bytes

```haskell
[2*n^2-3*n+2*k|n<-[1..],k<-[1..n]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ2W0km6Ec0CAUuz-3MTMPAVbhdzEAt94hYKizLwSBRWFksTsVAVDAwOFmKWlJWm6FjeVoo208uKMdI218rSNtLJr8mx0ow319GJ1siGMvNhYiMoFUApKAwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>9</s>  8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ḷ²’xRĖḄḣ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a positive integer, \$n\$, and yields a list of the first \$n\$ odd-odd triangular polka dot numbers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//4bi2wrLigJl4UsSW4biE4bij////Mzc)**

#### How?

Calculates the first \$T(n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\$ terms, and outputs the first \$n\$.

```
Ḷ²’xRĖḄḣ - Link: integer, n     e.g. 5
Ḷ        - lowered range (n)         [    0,    1,    2,    3,    4]
 ²       - square (vectorises)       [    0,    1,    4,    9,   16]
  ’      - decrement                 [   -1,    0,    3,    8,   15]
    R    - range (n)                 [    1,    2,    3,    4,    5]
   x     - repeat elements           [   -1,    0,    0,    3,    3,    3,    8,    8,    8,     8,     15,     15,     15,     15,     15]
    Ė    - enumerate                 [[1,-1],[2,0],[3,0],[4,3],[5,3],[6,3],[7,8],[8,8],[9,8],[10,8],[11,15],[12,15],[13,15],[14,15],[15,15]]
     Ḅ   - convert from base 2 (vectorises)
           ...i.e. [a,b] -> 2a+b     [    1,    4,    6,   11,   13,   15,   22,   24,   26,    28,     37,     39,     41,     43,     45]
       ḣ - head (to index n)         [    1,    4,    6,   11,   13]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
Þ∞:ẇ2Ḟ2vḞf
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnuKInjrhuocy4bieMnbhuJ5mIiwiIiwiIl0=) Outputs (theoretically) infinitely but crashes due to hitting the recursion limit caused by a bug.

```
Þ∞         # All positive integers
   ẇ       # Cut into slices of lengths...
Þ∞:        # Positive integers
    2Ḟ     # Get every second item
      2vḞ  # Get every second item of each
         f # Flatten the final array
```

Comment: `ṁĊ2Ċ2CNN` Husk, 8 with the exact same process

Comment: @Razetime maybe post it, theres no husk solution yet :P

Comment: This actually doesn't output infinitely - it stops after a bit due to max recursion depth (bug).

Answer (score 4):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 43 bytes

```rust
|n|((n+n).sqrt().round()-1.).powi(2)+n+n-1.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dczBCsIwDAbge58i3hLmiu1ExKGvMga2MNDMtR0enM9eg9iTLIeQn/8jYY4pe4Z7PzASvBTI3FwCfwLP6BtL9UU2nCEvvCByxaTjFBKSDuPMV6TaaNKP8TmgpUp6yblV3099jC6kzk0b9GgkQkdb@B3tP7GF7FdJU8hhlZhdMfZYkHrnDw)

A slightly modified version of loopy walt's answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 40 bytes

Prints the sequence forever.

```javascript
for(n=i=q=1;;n+=--i?2:q+(i=++q))print(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCPPNtO20NbQ2jpP21ZXN9PeyKpQWyPTVlu7UFOzoCgzr0QjT/P/fwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 32 bytes

```
; ; tk2* ;2^2* ;3* - + flat
$W1+
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-sclin) Returns an infinite list. This code is so weird...

For testing purposes (use `-i` flag when running locally):

```
; 50tk >A
; ; tk2* ;2^2* ;3* - + flat
$W1+
```

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
; ; tk 2* ; 2^ 2* ; 3* - + flat
$W 1+
```

`;` means "evaluate the next line as a function."

- `$W 1+` [1, ∞) as *n*
- `; ; tk 2*` `[[2][2 4][2 4 6][2 4 6 8]...]` as *k**2

  - this works because `tk` ("take") vectorizes the second argument
- `; 2^ 2* ; 3* - +` *n*^2*2 - *n**3 + *k**2

  - this whole segment is vectorized
- `flat` flatten

It's vectorizations all the way down!

---

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 19 bytes

```
2*""Q.5^.5- I2^ +1-
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-sclin) Port of @loopywalt/@att's answer. Takes a 1-based index, but the whole function vectorizes quite neatly too.

For testing purposes (use `-i` flag when running locally):

```
$W1+ ; 50tk >A
2*""Q.5^.5- I2^ +1-
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 34 bytes

```factor
[ 2 * dup √ .5 - 1 /i sq + 1 - ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYqxDcIwFAX7TPFqIIZEooEBEA0NoopSGOcHLMi3Y38XbMAMjMciJgKa0510vTbiQj4d94fdBjcKTHcMWq5fqD6xEes4/jJovtDfE1vjOoIPJPLwwbIg0piIzbRsi6JeoakW57bIDWrM0CWP9/MFtUaJCkuLOGI@WYk2D9pD5Q8)

Outputs the 1-indexed nth term of the sequence. Port of loopy walt's and att's [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253320/97916).

```
word  | data stack              | comment
------+-------------------------+-----------------
      | 5                       | example input
2     | 5 2                     |
*     | 10                      |
dup   | 10 10                   |
√     | 10 3.16227766016838     | square root
.5    | 10 3.16227766016838 0.5 |
-     | 10 2.66227766016838     |
1     | 10 2.66227766016838 1   |
/i    | 10 2                    | integer divide
sq    | 10 4                    | square
+     | 14                      |
1     | 14 1                    |
-     | 13                      | output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 55 bytes

```r
function(n,`?`=rbind)diffinv(rep(1:n*2+1?2,1?1:n))[n]+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPJ8E@wbYoKTMvRTMlMy0tM69Moyi1QMPQKk/LSNvQ3kjH0B7I1tSMzovVNvxfnFhQkFMJlDU00EnT/A8A)

Returns the 1-based nth term.

Comment: or [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/pfkJ@TnZiSX2L7P600L7kkMz9Po0JTQ0PDQqtCM07PVNdQU1Vf1UgzzkjbSKtC1/B/cWJBQU6lhqGVkakOTK/mfwA)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen you can post that...Also, it's vectorized; no `sapply` required!

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 31 bytes

```
[\+] flat (1,3...*)Z(2 Xxx^∞)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1up4FCcWqhg@z86RjtWIS0nsURBw1DHWE9PT0szSsNIIaKiIu5RxzzN/9YKxYkQxdFxhgYGsf8B)

This is an expression for the lazy infinite sequence of numbers.

- `(1, 3 ... *)` is the infinite sequence of odd numbers.
- `xx` is the replication operator, which replicates its left-hand side a number of times given by its right-hand side.
- `X` is the cross-product metaoperator.  Applied to the replication operator `xx`, it makes a new operator that replicates as a cross product.
- `^∞` is the unbounded range of increasing integers starting at zero.
- `2 Xxx ^∞` produces a list of 2 replicated each number of times from zero to infinity:  `(), (2,), (2, 2), (2, 2, 2), ...`.
- `Z` zips the odd numbers with the list of increasing numbers of twos: `(1, ()), (3, (2,)), (5, (2, 2)), (7, (2, 2, 2)), ...`.
- `flat` flattens that list: `1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, ...`.  That gives the list of differences between adjacent terms of the sequence.
- `[\+]` gives the list of partial sums of the previous sequence, which is the desired polka-dot sequence.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 37 bytes

```r
function(x)(((8*x)^.5-1)%/%2)^2+2*x-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/pfkJ@TnZiSX2L7P600L7kkMz9Po0JTQ0PDQqtCM07PVNdQU1Vf1UgzzkjbSKtC1xCuXsPQyshU8z8A)

An alternative to [Giuseppe's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253355/95126), here using a variant of [loopy walt's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253320/95126).

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 27 bytes

```
=INT((2*A1)^.5-.5)^2+2*A1-1
```

Direct implementation of [loopy walt's answer in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253320/38183) except it's shorter in Excel. Given the 1-based index computes a single value. Input is in `A1`. When copying the above into Excel, it will automatically add leading zeroes to change `.5` to `0.5`.

[image: Screenshot]

---

This **41 byte** solution prints the first 1,048,576 terms (or however many rows you have in your version of Excel):

```
=LET(r,ROW(A:A),INT((2*r)^.5-.5)^2+2*r-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 12 bytes

```
Þ∞:ɾ•y_ƛy$;f
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyI1IiwiIiwiw57iiJ46yb7igKJ5X8abeSQ7ZiIsIiIsIiJd)

Outputs the sequence forever.

### Explained

```
Þ∞:ɾ•y_ƛy$;f
Þ∞:          # Push two copies of an infinite list of positive integers
   ɾ         # In the second copy of the infinite list, push range [1, n] for each item
    •        # And mold the first copy of the infinite list to the shape of the second
     y_      # uninterleave the infinite list, giving two lists: the list of every second row starting at row 0, and the list of every second row starting at row 1. Discard the list starting at row 1.
       ƛy$;f # To each row in the remaining list, uninterleave the row, and return the list of every second item starting at index 0. Then flatten the result.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
ＮθＦθＦ⊕ι⊞υ×ιιＩＥ…υθ⊕⁺ι⊗κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TUw7DgIhFOz3FK98JFhaUWKzhWYLL8DiMxD5LR8TT49I5TTzycxoo7KOyvW@htTqrfmdMh5MLM@YYQiYvAadyVOo9EDLGGytGGwc7tZTQcthhGLZsg0VpSoVryqh/GhH0sT0ax6Mw//L5tocXmLb3fAvNiF6P/fT230B) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the first `n` terms of the sequence. Explanation: Port of @JonathanAllan's Jelly answer.

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
ＦθＦ⊕ι⊞υ×ιι
```

Create an array containing each of the squares `0`, `1`, `4`, `9`, ... `i²`, ... each repeated `i+1` times.

```
ＩＥ…υθ⊕⁺ι⊗κ
```

Take the first `n` elements of the array, and add to each the incremented doubled index (0-indexed).

20 bytes using the newer version of Charcoal on ATO:

```
ＮθＩＥ…ΣＥθＥ⊕ι×ιιθ⊕⁺ι⊗κ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FjcbPPMKSkv8SnOTUos0CjWtuQKKMvNKNJwTi0s0fBMLNJwrk3NSnTPyCzSCS3PBIoU6CiDKMy-5KDU3Na8kNUUjU1NHISQzN7VYI1NHIVMTCHQUCoEYWU1ATilY2iW_NCkHyM_WBAPrJcVJycVQ1yyPVtIty1GKXWgK4QMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the first `n` terms of the sequence. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ                      Input `n` as a number
       θ                Input `n`
      Ｅ                 Map over implicit range
          ι             Current value
         ⊕              Incremented
        Ｅ               Map over implicit range
            ι           Outer value
           ×            Multiplied by
             ι          Outer value
     Σ                  Concatenated
    …                   Truncated to length
              θ         Input `n`
   Ｅ                    Map over squares
                 ι      Current square
                ⁺       Plus
                   κ    Current index
                  ⊗     Doubled
               ⊕        Incremented
  Ｉ                     Cast to string
                        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 31 bytes

```
f(n)=floor(\sqrt{2n}-.5)^2+2n-1
```

Literally just a port of loopy walt's python answer, go upvote that answer too!

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zyoxm5ji9g)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5xvg9olfby)

Comment: `f(n)=floor((2n)^.5-.5)^2+2n-1` saves 2 bytes.

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan Did you try actually pasting that in? It doesn't work. `f(n)=floor((2n)^{.5}-.5)^2+2n-1` works but it's the same byte count as what I have (trust me, I checked before I posted this answer).

Comment: Oh lol, forgot to turn off the extension.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>9</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

-1 byte by porting [@corvus_192's Rust answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253353/52210), which is a slightly modified version of [@loopyWalt's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253320/52210), so make sure to upvote them as well!

Given \$n\$, it'll output the 1-based \$n^{th}\$ term (**8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**):

```
·Dtò<n+<
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0HaXksObbPK0bf7/NwUA) or [verify the first 25 items](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9k6upnr6TwqG2SgpK93/9D211KDm@yydO2@a/zHwA).

Given no input, it'll output the infinite sequence list (**9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**):

```
∞£ιнειн}˜
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8Q4vP7byw99xWEFl7es7//wA)

**Explanation:**

```python
·         # Double the (implicit) input-integer
 D        # Duplicate it
  t       # Take the square-root of the copy
   ò      # Round it to the nearest integer
    <     # Decrease it by 1
     n    # Square it
      +   # Add it to the doubled input that's still on the stack
       <  # Decrease it by 1
          # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
∞         # Push a positive infinite list: [1,2,3,4,5,...]
 £        # Split it into parts of itself (since there is no input):
          #  [[1],[2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],...]
  ι       # Uninterleave it into two parts
   н      # Pop and only keep the first
    ε  }  # Map over each remaining inner list:
     ιн   #  Do the same for those
        ˜ # Flatten the list of lists
          # (after which the infinite list is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), <s>68</s> 65 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [@Sʨɠɠan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/s%ca%a8%c9%a0%c9%a0an)*

```c
i;r;main(s){for(;i<=r||(i=0,s+=++r+ ++r);i+=2)printf("%d ",s+i);}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OT49OXnBgqWlJWm6FjcdM62LrHMTM_M0ijWr0_KLNKwzbWyLamo0Mm0NdIq1bbW1i7QVgISmdaa2rZFmQVFmXkmahpJqioISUDpT07oWYhDUPJi5AA)

Comment: `)|(` can be `,`

Comment: 63: `i;r;main(s){for(;i>r?i=0,s+=++r+ ++r:1;i+=2)printf("%d ",s+i);}`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
d:√ṙ‹²+‹
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIyNcabIiwiZDriiJrhuZnigLnCsivigLkiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Port of 05AB1E, which is a port of Rust, so make sure to upvote those answers!

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 24 bytes

```
((RTDBa-0.5)//1)E2+DBa-1
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCIoKFJUREJhLTAuNSkvLzEpRTIrREJhLTEiLCIiLCIiLCIxMCJd)

Port of loopy walt's Python answer, so go upvote his answer too!

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 39 bytes

Prints the infinite sequence.

```
130>$:2+@$:1+@v
2$-1v!?:$oan:{<}+
~+}v>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/39DYwE7FykjbQcXKUNuhjMtIRdewTNHeSiU/Mc@q2qZWm6tOu7bM7v9/AA)

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 38 bytes

Prints the nth term 1-indexed.

```
:8*$2*1v
}(?!v1+>::*{:
+1-n>2-2,:1%-:*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38pCS8VIy7CMq1bDXrHMUNvOykqr2opL21A3z85I10jHylBV10rr////umWGZgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 10 bytes

```
2*Đ√½-Ɩ²+⁻
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9weXT//zIqxJDiiJrCvS3GlsKyK@KBu///MTA)

```
              implicit input
2*            double
  Đ           duplicate on the stack
   √          take the square root of top
    ½-        subtract 1/2
      Ɩ²      cast to an integer and square
        +     add the stack
         ⁻    decrement
              implicit output
```

Port of [loopy walt's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253320/52210)

If floating-point returns are allowed, then 9 bytes is possible:

```
2*Đ√⎶⁻²+⁻
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/fSOvIhEcdsx71bXvUuPvQJm0g@f@/oQEA)

Port of [corvus_192's Rust answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253309/triangular-polkadot-numbers/253353#253353)