# Triangular honeycomb numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

From the infinite triangular array of positive integers, suppose we repeatedly select all numbers at Euclidean distance of \$\sqrt{3}\$, starting from 1:

$$
\underline{1} \\
\;2\; \quad \;3\; \\
\;4\; \quad \;\underline{5}\; \quad \;6\; \\
\;\underline{7}\; \quad \;8\; \quad \;9\; \quad \underline{10} \\
11 \quad 12 \quad \underline{13} \quad 14 \quad 15 \\
16 \quad \underline{17} \quad 18 \quad 19 \quad \underline{20} \quad 21 \\
\underline{22} \quad 23 \quad 24 \quad \underline{25} \quad 26 \quad 27 \quad \underline{28} \\
\cdots
$$

Alternatively, you may think of it as "leave centers of a honeycomb pattern and cross out boundaries".

The resulting sequence (not yet on OEIS, unlike the [polkadot numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/253309/78410)) is as follows:

```
1, 5, 7, 10, 13, 17, 20, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34, 38, 41, 44, 46, 49, 52, 55, 58, 61, 64,
68, 71, 74, 77, 79, 82, 85, 88, 91, 94, 97, 100, 103, 107, 110, 113, 116, 119,
121, 124, 127, 130, 133, 136, 139, 142, 145, 148, 151, 155, 158, 161, 164, 167, 170,
172, 175, 178, 181, 184, 187, 190, ...
```

The task is to output this sequence.

[sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) I/O rules apply. You can choose to implement one of the following:

- Given the index \$n\$ (0- or 1-based), output the \$n\$th term of the sequence.
- Given a positive integer \$n\$, output the first \$n\$ terms of the sequence.
- Take no input and output the entire sequence by

  - printing infinitely or
  - returning a lazy list or a generator.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 34 bytes

Takes as input an integer \$ n \$, and outputs the \$ n \$-th term of the sequence (0-indexed).

```python
lambda n:3*n-~((n*24+1)**.5%6%5<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY47bsMwEER7n2IbA6SiBFr@ZUQ30A0cFwpiOQYc2hDcpMnVlRkVOxhi3nLn8fv8vle/zsPHept@Pr8mqQff1Nc/Y2rjwovapnmL@7SP72rXUQY5aiuxldyKdhiPgXfwzmEQudKKB@UDBj7AB/iQMD22wUVwEVlClpAl@Ayf4TP@y@AKuAKuIOuR9cj67S4Pd7zc8bn12IpoomBVnVIChYjfqhLxRDyR4CiRggMaucFayl7KYspmmvhB5geZG5lIJlKIFCKFSN@ddvN9kSrXKstUL2dzO1czWnvYyWO51qeprcymWhkGGY/1ZNd/)

#### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 43 bytes

Outputs the sequence forever.

```python
n=1
while[print(n//8-~(n**.5%6%5<1))]:n+=24
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8/WkKs8IzMnNbqgKDOvRCNPX99Ct04jT0tLz1TVTNXUxlBTM9YqT9vWyOT/fwA)

Comment: Besides, for an infinite output, this could work: `n=0\n
while 1:print(3*n-~((n*24+1)**.5%6%5<1));n+=1` which would be 49 bytes,  if you consider '\n' to be 1 byte as an actual newline

Comment: Yes of course, and it can be taken down to 44 bytes by two more tricks: incrementing by `3` and placing the `print` in the condition.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 45 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [@Grain Ghost](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/grain-ghost).

```haskell
[sum[0..n]+k|n<-[0..],k<-[0..n],mod(n+k)3==1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ2W0km6Ec0CAUuz-3MTMPAVbhdzEAt94hYKizLwSBRWFksTsVAVDAwOFmKWlJWm6Fjd1o4tLc6MN9PTyYrWza_JsdEHsWJ1sCCMvVic3P0UjTztb09jW1jAWomkBlILSAA)

Comment: `sum[1..n]` is shorter than `div(n^2+n)2`.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 55 bytes

Prints the sequence forever.

```javascript
for(n=i=1;;i++)for(j=0;j<=i*3;n+=3+!j-(j++==i))print(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FccxCoAwDAXQs7g1hoLSRYj/MEUQkiGWWnr9iG97Vmd9r65t5HlE3E9PDsUuosz017CJndC1iDMKL5aTMQNK1Lr6SE4RHw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>24</s> 17 bytes

```
Ｉ…⌕Ａ⭆⊕θ⭆⊕ι﹪⁺ιλ³1Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bclBCoMwEEDRq4irCdhF7bKrIhRcWARPkCZDDYyTGJOCp5/OAbp5i//darOLlkTmHLjAYA/ldITDGhM8A/sHESxF72eyCUZ2GTfkgh520zX/T9AzRV8pwkz1gNA1pOlmjNpeW3XkVMurbm/MoNncRfpeLl/6AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the first `n` terms. Explanation: Now a port of @JonathanAllan's Jelly answer, but taking some inspiration from @Steffan's Vyxal answer to save a byte.

```
      θ             Input `n`
     ⊕              Incremented
    ⭆               Map over implicit range and join
         ι          Current value
        ⊕           Incremented
       ⭆            Map over implicit range and join
            ι       Outer value
           ⁺        Plus
             λ      Inner value
          ﹪         Modulo
              ³     Literal integer 3
  ⌕Ａ                Find all indices of
               1    Literal string `1`
 …                  Truncated to length
                Ｎ   Input `n` as an integer
Ｉ                   Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Comment: Another way of looking at it is that the `2`s appear in runs of `n` starting at the `n`th pentagonal number, so `0` `2`s at `0`, `1` `2` at `1`, `2` `2`s at `5`, `3` `2`s at `12`, `4` `2`s at `22`, `5` `2`s at `35` etc.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
Þ::ʀ+3ḊfT›
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnjo6yoArM+G4imZU4oC6IiwiMTAw4bqOIiwiIl0=)

Outputs the infinite sequence.

-6 bytes (compared to my previous answer below) thanks to porting @Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer, so make sure to upvote that!

```
Þ::ʀ+3ḊfT›
Þ:         # Push an infinite list of non-negative integers
  :        # Duplicate
   ʀ+      # For each n in this list, add n to each item in a range [0..n]. This produces an infinite list like [[0], [1, 2], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], ...]
     3Ḋ    # For each inner item, is it divisible by three?
       f   # Flatten
        T  # Get truthy (0-based) indices
         › # Increment
```

Previously:

### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes

```
Þ∞ƛʀ+'ǒ1=;nɽ∑+;f
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnuKInsabyoArJ8eSMT07bsm94oiRKztmIiwiMTAw4bqOIiwiIl0=)

Outputs the infinite sequence.

```
Þ∞ƛʀ+'ǒ1=;nɽ∑+;f
Þ∞ƛ               # Map n over positive integers:
   ʀ+             #  For each in [0..n], add n
     '            #  Filter for:
      ǒ           #   Modulo 3
       1=         #   Equals one?
         ;        #  Close filter
          nɽ∑+    #  For each, add the sum of [0..n-1]
              ;   # Close map
               f  # Flatten
```

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 12 bytes

```
24*›√6%₅$T+›
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIzMMqAxpsiLCIyNCrigLriiJo2JeKChSRUK+KAuiIsIiIsIiJd)

Outputs the \$n\$th  element of the sequence. Port of @dingledooper's answer, so uvpote that!

```
24*›√6%₅$T+›
24*          # Multiply the input by 24
   ›         # Increment
    √        # Square root
     6%      # Modulo 6
       ₅     # Is it divisible by 5? (Returns 1 or 0)
        $T+  # Add input * 3
           › # Increment
```

Comment: Wow, that FizzBuzz builtin actually came in useful for you?

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>35</s> <s>30</s> 29 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to [Sʨɠɠan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/s%ca%a8%c9%a0%c9%a0an)
-1 byte thanks to [G B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/18535/g-b)

Returns `n`th item of the sequence. Same technique as [Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253422/11261) and [Vyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253427/11261) answers; give them upvotes.

```ruby
->n{3*n-~33[(n*24+1)**0.5%6]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhZ7de3yqo218nTrjI2jNfK0jEy0DTW1tAz0TFXNYmshanYaGeiVZOamFiuk5HMpKBQouEXHG8ZypealQOQXLIDQAA)

Comment: 30 bytes: `->n{3*n-~1[(n*24+1)**0.5%6%5]}`

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan Very clever. Thanks!

Comment: 29: `->n{3*n-~33[(n*24+1)**0.5%6]}`

Comment: @GB Clever as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Ports of [*@Sʨɠɠan*'s Vyxal answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253427/52210), where the first is a port of [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253448/52210) and the second is a port of [*@dingledooper*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253422/52210), so make sure to upvote them as well!

Given no input, it'll output the infinite sequence as list (**11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**):

```
∞<DÝ+˜3Öƶ0K
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8G5fDc7VPzzE@PO3YNgPv//8B)

Given \$n\$, it'll output the 0-based \$n^{th}\$ term (**12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**)

```
Ð$24*>t6%5ÖO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8AQVIxMtuxIzVdPD0/z//7cAAA) or [verify the first 25 items](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9k6uZnr6TwqG2SgpK93//DEwz9jEy07ErMVE0PT/P/r/MfAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
∞             # Push an infinite list of positive integers: [1,2,3,...]
 <            # Decrease each by 1 to make it non-negative: [0,1,2,...]
  D           # Duplicate this infinite list
   Ý          # Map each to a [0,val]-ranged list in the copy
    +         # Add the values of the lists at the same positions together
     ˜        # Flatten this list of lists
      3Ö      # Check for each integer whether it's divisible by 3
        ƶ     # Multiply each check by its 1-based index
         0K   # And then remove all 0s (the falsey checks)
              # (after which the infinite list is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
Ð             # Triplicate the (implicit) input-integer
 $            # Push 1 and the input-integer yet again
  24*         # Multiply the top input by 24
     >        # Increase it by 1
      t       # Take the square-root of that
       6%     # Modulo-6
         5Ö   # Check if that is divisible by 5
           O  # And then sum all five values on the stack together:
              #  input + input + input + 1 + (sqrt(input*24)%6%5==0)
              # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŻrḤ$3ḍFTḣ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a non-negative integer, \$n\$, and yields the first \$n\$ triangular honeycomb numbers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4wgbZVHTWuADOOHO3rdQh7uWPz//38zEwA)**

#### How?

The triangle's \$i^{\text{th}}\$ row contributes every third element starting with the \$(3 - (i+1\pmod 3))^{\text{th}}\$ element...

```
ŻrḤ$3ḍFTḣ - Link: integer, n    e.g. 4
Ż         - zero-range (n)           [ 0,  1,    2,      3,        4]
   $      - last two links as a monad:
  Ḥ       -   double                 [ 0,  2,    4,      6,        8]
 r        -   inclusive range        [[0],[1,2],[2,3,4],[3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7,8]]
    3     - three                    3
     ḍ    - divides?                 [[1],[0,0],[0,1,0],[1,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0,0]
      F   - flatten                  [ 1,  0,0,  0,1,0,  1,0,0,1,  0,0,1,0,0]
       T  - truthy indices           [ 1,          5,    7,   10,     13    ]
        ḣ - head (to index n)        [1,5,7,10]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
M*)√6%5%┬ΓΣ)
```

Port of [*@dingledooper*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253422/52210).
Given \$n\$, it'll output the 0-based \$n^{th}\$ term.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/99XS/NRxywzVVPVR1PWnJt8brHm//8GXIZcRlzGXCZcplxmXOZcFlyWXIYGAA)

Unfortunately `÷` (*is divisible by* builtin) is incorrectly implemented and doesn't support a float argument, otherwise the `5%┬` could have been `5÷` for -1 byte.

**Explanation:**

```python
M*            # Multiply the (implicit) input-integer by 24
  )           # Increase it by 1
   √          # Take the square-root of that
    6%        # Modulo-6
      5%┬     # Check if it's divisible by 5:
      5%      #  Modulo-5
        ┬     #  Check if it's equal to 0.0
         Γ    # Wrap the top four values into a list
              # (which uses the implicit input three times)
          Σ   # Sum this list together
           )  # Increase it by 1
              # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 8.5 bytes (17 nibbles)

```
`?+.,~.+$,$%$3 2
```

Somewhat modified port of [Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253448/95126): upvote that.
Outputs the infinite sequence.

```
`?+.,~.+$,$%$3 2
    ,~              # 1..infinity
   .                # map over each n
         ,$         #   1..n
       +$           #   add n 
      .    %$3      #   each modulo 3
  +                 # now flatten this list-of-lists
`?                  # and get indices of
               2    # all elments equal to 2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 59 bytes

```c
j,i;main(x){for(;i%3||printf("%d ",x);i=++i>j*2?++j:i)++x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYzLCsIwEEX3fkUoFBIzgs2zGtRvKZXKlBqluAhYvz3exYED98yMh3EZ8qPWmTg9B86yqO/0WmXi1m7be@X8mWTT3kVDRSW@aM3XeW9uWs9nVlqX9Ku1I@FJRBLdEVgAN3BjACbTk7CorANwB3dwF8AJ1@g8Oo8tYAuOdgEe4RFdxL@Irjd/)

Full program.

Iterate x=[1..] combined with growing series *i..* of lines of the pyramid where starting value *j* increases by one.
When *i%3 == 0* prints *x*

```c
0 12 234 3456 45678 56789..
1 ..  5..7.10..13,  17, 20
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 43 bytes

```hs
[y-x+sum[1..x]|x<-[1..],y<-[1,4..x*2],y>=x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzfDoIgHEZf5XfhRX/QJSLYFr1GF8YFs0yWOpa2YevZo8@Lsx34DnR2et77Prb6GuslDfvpPdR5lgXzDad0NcOWVZjA5Y7jdNbBxMG6kTT5lxtnSsiOt@Tj/MXN3UbrLXIqGSlG@QEUAM7hnANMvGJUoCoEgAu4gAsJjniNrkRXYpPYJDYJV3AFV/hPoau4aeOvaXv7mGLaeP8H)

Using similar approach of my C answer